# Mandrill App inline html form in email

Tags: html, email, mandrill

Is it possible to put html form elements in mandrill app and send emails? I tried various possible things to send textbox and radio button but it does not show up in gmail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't use forms in emails.

"*The short of it is that email clients consider email forms to be a security risk. While some email clients simply warn you of potential danger, others outright disable the forms. So if your client wants to send out a form, they should know that most of their recipients will never be able to use it. And for those who can, they’ll think twice about submitting data when they see a warning from their email client.*" - [campaignmonitor](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/2435/how-forms-perform-in-html-emai/).

Comment: I really don't think you should control over user's content. You can only advice not to use forms, but that's really unfair. I need to give my users a key which is submitted via POST. How can I solve it then except sending it as "raw", but that costs me more traffic data.